# How can I know that Android SharedPreferences are saved successfully?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am saving some data to SharedPreference from a fragment and want use these data in other fragments. But I want to perform fragment transaction only if SharedPreferences are saved successfully, otherwise, other fragments would not be able to retrieve data (since using those SharedPreference values to retrieve data).

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

  ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...

  public void setSharedPref(String key, String val) {
      SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
      editor.putString(key, val);
      editor.commit();

  }

  public String fetchSharedPref(String key) {
      SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      String val = sharedPref.getString(key, Constant.SHARED_PREF_DEFAULT_MSN);
      return val;
  }
}
```

How can I be sure that SharedPreferences are saved successfully?
Is there any way to implement a callback that will be invoked only if SharedPreferences saved successfully?

Comment: As far as I know, `Editor.commit` returns the same thing that you need

Comment: You can judge it by Editor.commit()

Comment: Editor.commit()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the **[docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html?hl=en#ReadSharedPreference)**.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
editor.commit();
```

Then go and check `commit()` method [**here**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html?hl=en#commit()).

> **Return type:** boolean
>
> **Description:** Returns true if the new values were successfully written to persistent storage.

Comment: Your link is in the Russian language. Please change it to English.

Comment: Done. I thought this page is not translated yet.

Answer (score 2):

Find the solution :

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt("Your Key", "Your value");
boolean savedOrNot = editor.commit();

if(savedOrNot){
// Successfully saved
}else{
// Not saved
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Form [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit())

> **apply()**
>
> This saves your data into memory immediately and saves the data to
>   disk on a separate thread. So there is no chance of blocking the main
>   thread (your app won’t hang).
>
> It is the preferred technique but has only been available since
>   Gingerbread (API 9, Android 2.3).
>
> **commit()**
>
> Calling this will save the data to the file however, the process is
>   carried out in the thread that called it, stopping everything else
>   until the save is complete. **It returns true on successful completion,
>   false on failure.**
>
> Use `commit()` if you need confirmation of the success of saving your
>   data or if you are developing for pre-Gingerbread devices. `commit()`
>   has been available since API 1

so your can check status at `editor.commit();`

`commit()` returns `true` if the save works, `false` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

commit() returns true if the save works, false otherwise.
You can alter your method as follows.

```
public boolean setSharedPref(String key, String val) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString(key, val);
    return editor.commit()
}
```

Difference between apply and commit https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html

Comment: I think you replace whole if else with `return editor.commit()`

Answer (score 1):

The editor.commit() will return boolean value , which will let you know if data has been saved.

If you would like to analyze all the data saved in shared preferences and sqlite ,then i would recommend using [facebook stetho](https://github.com/facebook/stetho)

Its a debug bridge for android , you can check all of your shared preferences data and sql databases for debugging.